# When radio button is focused, change border of its :after

Tags: html, css

I have two custom styled radio buttons, and am trying to highlight a border of the one that is focused, but since I have styled them with :before and :after I can't seem to get the :focus target right.

Here's a jsFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/o5htfhdm/2/ 
The desired effect is that when a radio button is clicked(focused) its border is blue, but as soon as the user clicks somewhere else, for example in to the text input below the border will go back to black

The change the color of the radio button border we need only

```
input[type="radio"]:after{
    border-color: #000; 
}
```

So now what I am trying to do is

```
input[type="radio"]:focus > input[type="radio"]:after{
    border-color: blue;
}
```

But that doesn't work

Comment: @Paulie_D This is definitely a duplicate of that question, as I was able to style the radio buttons with :before and :after, I am just trying to add extra functionality

Comment: It's at the top....Have you checked this is Firefox...it doesn't work **at all**. `input` elements aren't supposed to support pseudo-elements, Chrome is odd in that respect.

Comment: @Paulie_D, well I don't mind it has the default look in Firefox, that can't stop me from changing the look of it for the more fortunate users of Chrome

Comment: Even if it did work it would be something like `input[type="radio"]:focus:after`

Comment: `input[type="radio"]:after{
  border-color: red !important;
}` works, but `input[type="radio"]:focus:after{
  border-color: red !important;
}` doesnt

Comment: You sure? - https://jsfiddle.net/me0j4wqp/

Comment: @Paulie_D wow ok, so this is so broken :D It works in chrome, changes the border color to red, but not in Safari, even though in Safari the radio buttons are still properly styled with :after and :before.

Comment: That's why using a pseudo-element isn't recommended here. Use a `label` and, if necessary, pseudo-elements on **that**.

Comment: @Paulie_D I was kinda ripping of what bootstrap does, didn't realize they didn't cover their ass in Firefox.. Even the demo doesn't work there http://bootswatch.com/paper/ :(